# Find the last element that has appeared DOM html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I have a code that puts images on a table(html), and I want to focus on the image that has just appeared.
I know that i have to use $(this) but i don't know how, here is my code

```
function positioning(year, mon) {
    $('#' + year + ' .' + mon).prepend('<img class="black_point" src="./images/circle.png"/>');//that adds the image
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var images = table.getElementsByTagName("img");
    //here I need the current image I had just add to send to that function
    function connect(images) {
        var tabBcr = table.getBoundingClientRect();
        var imgBcr = image.getBoundingClientRect();
        x = imgBcr.left + (imgBcr.width / 2) - tabBcr.left;
        y = imgBcr.top + (imgBcr.height / 2) - tabBcr.top;
    } 
}
```

I hope I have explained well .

Comment: If you are calling `positioning()` method more than once, you are rendering invalid HTML markup. **IDs must be unique on document context**. And FYI, an image isn't a focusable input by default, you need to set a tabindex attribute for making it focusable

Comment: What A.Wolff said is true.  What you can do, once you fix that issue, is create the image in a variable before appending it to the DOM.  Then after you've appended it, call .focus() on that variable.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry I was confused, is not the id  is the class

Comment: Also, just cause it's kinda bugging me.  Why are you intermixing javascript selectors and jquery selectors?

Comment: So please try: `$('<img class="black_point" src="./images/circle.png" tabindex="-1"/>').prependTo('#' + year + ' .' + mon).focus();`

Comment: Well im a beginner so when I don't know how to do something with jquery I use javascript

Comment: note : to focus on an img element you need to explicitly specify tabindex property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work, add this where you want to get that img element:

```
var imgelem=$('#' + year + ' .' + mon).find("img:first");
```

Comment: Yes it works, now i have in imgelem the image isn't it?

Comment: Um but now , I'm doing this: `$('#' + anio + ' .' + mon).prepend('<img class="black_point" src="./images/circulo.png"/>');
    var imgelem=$('.' + anio + ' .' + mon).find("img:first");
    var position = imgelem.position();
    alert( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );` but not recognize the property left, maybe it can be cause imgelem?

Comment: Write same as when you prepend to it .. `var imgelem=$('#' + anio + ' .' + mon).find("img:first");`